# архитектура разработки веб приложения

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, веб-сервер

если я делаю бэкенд часть на nodejs, все что касается сервера надо вынести в отдельную
папку и отдельно там установить node_modules? или можно смешать серверные зависимости с фронтовым package.json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У сервера обычно другие модули, которые работают внутри ноды при старте серверного приложения. А у клиента модули компилируются вебпаком или другими утилитами, и присутствовать на сервере не должны. Представьте ситуацию, что вы на сервере запускаете инсталляцию (загрузку модулей из удалённого хранилища в папку). Тогда фронтовые модули не должны участвовать в этом процессе. Иначе они просто туда загрузятся, но не будут использоваться. Страшного в этом ничего нет, просто лишняя работа.

Если фронтовые модули например все девелоперские (установлены с флагом save-dev), то можно иметь один package.json, потому что на сервере они не будут инсталлироваться.